# Embed edit code is not working, how can i solve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this code, but it doesn't work, it's returning some function, how can I solve it?

```js
module.exports = (client, message, edit) => {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed
    const { prefix } = require("./config.json")
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'edit')) {
        let messageID = message.content.split(' ').slice(1, 2).join(' ');
        let myMessage = message.content.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ');
        if (!messageID) return;
        if (!myMessage) return;
        message.channel.fetchMessage(messageID)
            .then(m => m.edit(embed)
                .then(message.delete().catch(() => { return })))
            .catch(e => console.error(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: `not working` is not enough to go on.  Can you post an error msg or something to describe the issue?

Comment: There was no error on the console and the bot did not send any messages in the chat

Comment: How wich you call that`s module?

Comment: You call this command in the same channel to which the message was sent for editing?

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> .then(message.delete().catch(() => { return })))
> ```

That line is the source of your problem. [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes a callback *function*, but you haven't provided it with one. What's actually being passed to it is the value returned by `message.delete().catch(() => { return }))`, which is a pending promise.

This is the (working) equivalent to what it looks like you're attempting to accomplish:

```js
message.channel.fetchMessage(messageID)
  .then(m => m.edit(embed)) // will run after above (unless above was rejected)
  .then(m => m.delete())    // will run after above (unless above was rejected)
  .catch(console.error);    // will catch errors from any of the 3 promises
```